# Why does Date.strptime not throw ArgumentError in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my local rails console passing 9/31/2011 returns 10/1/2011

```
[1] pry(main)> Date.strptime("09/31/2011", '%m/%d/%Y')
=> Sat, 01 Oct 2011
```

In heroku console it throws an ArgumentError:

```
irb(main):002:0> Date.strptime("09/31/2011", '%m/%d/%Y')
ArgumentError: invalid date
    from (irb):2:in `strptime'
```

Comment: what are the ruby versions on each?

Comment: ruby 2.4.5, 
Rails 4.2.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check that your Gemfile dev dependencies don't include something that could mess with Date's strptime function.

For example, the Timecop gem sets an alias for Date.strptime to this method:
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/timecop/Date.strptime_with_mock_date

Which just ends up calling `Time.strptime(str, fmt).to_date`.

This behavior looks very similar to what you reported:

```
irb(main):001:0> Date.strptime("09/31/2011", '%m/%d/%Y')
ArgumentError: invalid date
    from (irb):1:in 'strptime'
irb(main):002:0> Time.strptime("09/31/2011", '%m/%d/%Y').to_date
=> Sat, 01 Oct 2011
```

Comment: Seems like that was the issue.
I had the timecop gem in `group :development, :test` section